# change window/frame gtk3 pygtk and pass parameters

Tags: python-3.x, pygtk

I created an easy game with pygtk that starts whit start page (option, new game, ecc) and when i press newgame button i want to change window/frame and replace with the game window.
Here is a sample of a code:

```py
import gi

gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk


class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Title of Window")
        self.set_border_width(20)
        layout = Gtk.Box(spacing=10)
        self.add(layout)
        self.set_default_size(300, 500)

        label_start = Gtk.Label("This is start page")
        layout.pack_start(label_start, True, True, 0)

        new_game_button = Gtk.Button("NEW GAME")
        new_game_button.connect("clicked", self.start_new_game)
        new_game_button.set_border_width(20)
        new_game_button.set_valign(Gtk.Align.CENTER)
        layout.pack_start(new_game_button, True, True, 0)

    def start_new_game(self, widget):
        # here is were i want to go to first page
        pass


class FirstPage(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Title of Window")
        self.set_border_width(20)
        layout = Gtk.Box(spacing=10)
        self.add(layout)
        self.set_default_size(300, 500)

        label_start = Gtk.Label("This is start page")
        layout.pack_start(label_start, True, True, 0)

        return_button = Gtk.Button("NEW GAME")
        return_button.connect("clicked", self.return_start_page)
        return_button.set_border_width(20)
        return_button.set_valign(Gtk.Align.CENTER)
        layout.pack_start(return_button, True, True, 0)


def return_start_page(self, widget):
    # here is were i want to manage the event to return to start page
    pass


window = MainWindow()
window.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

"start new game" and "return start page" are methods were i want to manage this event.
I would also need to pass additional parameters to New Game.
Can i simply add them on **init** of game window?
PS: "game window" is MainWindow in the example and FirstPage represents my "start page" with option menu and others thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

You should create only a Main window with one **Gtk.Box** (as container), and the 2 "screens" should be 2 extra **Gtk.Box**es in the container box. E.g.:

```py
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk


class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(title="Title of Window")
        self.set_border_width(20)
        self.set_default_size(300, 500)

        container = Gtk.Box()
        self.add(container)
        container.show()

        self.main = Main(self)
        container.add(self.main)

        self.first_page = FirstPage(self)
        container.add(self.first_page)


class Main(Gtk.Box):
    def __init__(self, parent_window):
        super().__init__(spacing=10)
        self.__parent_window = parent_window

        label_start = Gtk.Label("This is start page")
        self.pack_start(label_start, True, True, 0)

        new_game_button = Gtk.Button("NEW GAME")
        new_game_button.connect("clicked", self.start_new_game)
        new_game_button.set_border_width(20)
        new_game_button.set_valign(Gtk.Align.CENTER)
        self.pack_start(new_game_button, True, True, 0)

    def start_new_game(self, *args):
        self.__parent_window.first_page.show_all()
        self.hide()


class FirstPage(Gtk.Box):
    def __init__(self, parent_window):
        super().__init__(spacing=10)
        self.__parent_window = parent_window

        label_start = Gtk.Label("This is second page")
        self.pack_start(label_start, True, True, 0)

        return_button = Gtk.Button("END GAME")
        return_button.connect("clicked", self.return_start_page)
        return_button.set_border_width(20)
        return_button.set_valign(Gtk.Align.CENTER)
        self.pack_start(return_button, True, True, 0)

    def return_start_page(self, *args):
        self.__parent_window.main.show_all()
        self.hide()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = MainWindow()
    window.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
    window.main.start_new_game()
    window.show()
    Gtk.main()
```

## Alternative solution

You can use [Gtk.Notebook](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layout.html#notebook) and switching tabs. E.g.:

```py
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk


class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(title="Title of Window")
        self.set_border_width(20)
        self.set_default_size(300, 500)

        container = Gtk.Notebook()
        container.set_show_tabs(False)
        self.add(container)

        main = Main(container)
        container.append_page(main)

        first_page = FirstPage(container)
        container.append_page(first_page)


class Main(Gtk.Box):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(spacing=10)
        self.__parent = parent

        label_start = Gtk.Label("This is start page")
        self.pack_start(label_start, True, True, 0)

        new_game_button = Gtk.Button("NEW GAME")
        new_game_button.connect("clicked", self.start_new_game)
        new_game_button.set_border_width(20)
        new_game_button.set_valign(Gtk.Align.CENTER)
        self.pack_start(new_game_button, True, True, 0)

    def start_new_game(self, widget):
        self.__parent.set_current_page(1)


class FirstPage(Gtk.Box):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(spacing=10)
        self.__parent = parent

        label_start = Gtk.Label("This is second page")
        self.pack_start(label_start, True, True, 0)

        return_button = Gtk.Button("END GAME")
        return_button.connect("clicked", self.return_start_page)
        return_button.set_border_width(20)
        return_button.set_valign(Gtk.Align.CENTER)
        self.pack_start(return_button, True, True, 0)

    def return_start_page(self, widget):
        self.__parent.set_current_page(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = MainWindow()
    window.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
    window.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```